# Can you make an opportunity attack against a moving object?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, opportunity-attack, objects

With the recent addition of the revisited artificer class to 5e, I did a quick playthrough with a level 3 artillerist. The artillerist can summon a turret; an object (not a construct) with a speed of 15 and they can command the turret to move as part of a bonus action. When I attempted to move the turret out of melee range of an enemy NPC, the DM tried to make an attack of opportunity against it. I pointed out to him that opportunity attacks are made against *creatures*, and the turret is not a creature.

This got me thinking about whether or not you can make opportunity attacks against other objects that move, such as a vehicle or even a rolling stone.

Comment: @MarkWells Please don't [answer in the comments](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/should-users-refrain-from-answers-or-partial-answers-in-comments). Use them only for trying to clarify or improve the question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Objects do not trigger Opportunity Attacks

Your assessment is correct. The [rules for OA](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#OpportunityAttacks) state that (emphasis mine):

> You can make an opportunity attack when a hostile **creature** that you can see moves out of your reach.

As you can see the rules are very clear. Unless something is a creature it can't provoke an OA.

Further, the turret created by the artillerist is not a creature but an object. From the [UA](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/UA-Artificer-2019.pdf):

> The turret is a magical **object** that occupies its space and that has crablike legs

Thus, the turret also can't provoke an Opportunity Attack.

It may seem reasonable for a DM to want to change the Artificer turret to a creature (likely a construct is appropriate). However, do keep in mind that this changes a lot more than just Opportunity Attacks. There are a number of spells and abilities that can only affect either creatures or objects or work differently with them.

### With the release of Eberron: Rising from the Last War nothing changes

This question was asked about a playtest UA version of the Artificer which has now been officially released in Eberron: Rising from the Last War. The wording of the artillerist turret has changed, it is called an [eldritch cannon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/erftlw/character-creation-class-artificer#EldritchCannon) now. However, it is still an object:

> The cannon is a magical object.

Therefore, this version of the artillerist cannon also does not provoke Opportunity Attacks, as explained previously in this answer.

Comment: I totally agree that this is correct interpretation of RAW (and I have upvoted for this reason). However common sense strongly suggests that it should actually be a construct type and thus subject to OAs. and this represents yet another flaw in the 2019 Artificer class. If I was going to allow the Artificer in a game I ran (which I won't) this would be a house rule.

Comment: I agree that this is the correct interpretation of RAW, but it is such an illogical conclusion that I can't bring myself to upvote. This would be improved if you add something about how a sensible DM would likely rule it.

Comment: @SeriousBri I added a note to that effect but I do feel that changing something from object to creature is a very drastic change and should be done with care.

Comment: @Sdjz It isn't so much changing the type (I wouldn't even give that a second thought actually), but that an opportunity attack represents taking a swing at something moving away from you, and having that something have to be of a specific type is a bit arbitrary to me. If the ground gave way and my players wanted to swing at it I would let them. Got my +1 though.

Comment: @SeriousBri I'm not sure I'd allow OAs in such a circumstance since you also have to be using your own action/movement but not when one is pushed which to me suggests that intentionally moving (carelessly) is what provides the opening for OAs. This is, however, entirely a matter of opinion on how to interpret this.

Comment: @Sdjz forced movement is a conundrum I must admit, because the disengage action is how you carefully move. I think of it as more of a balancing factor than anything that makes sense in the narrative, but I can see your point of view - thank you.

Answer (score -5):

Whilst RAW you are correct, there are items that can mess this rule up (Apparatus of the crab/Kawlish). This puts the player/enemy in a vehicle meaning you can't target it.  How I would rule it as a DM, is any vehicle that has a player in it, can be targetted with an AoO, however your example of a turret cannot.  If you stuck to the rules as written, could you specify that a Golem was a construct and not a  creature, therefore could not AoO against them???

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Constructs are a type of creature, not objects.